# Only default constructor accepted for a typescript class

Tags: typescript

I have 2 typescript files. One implements a SourceContext class:

```
export class SourceContext {
    constuctor(sourceId: string) {
        this._sourceId = sourceId;
    }
...
}
```

and in the other file I want to use this exported class (both files are in the same folder in my NodeJS module):

```
import { SourceContext } from './SourceContext';

export class Service {
    public load(file: string) {
        var context = new SourceContext(file);
    }
}
```

However I get the error:

> file: 'file:///...../src/index.ts' severity: 'Fehler' message:
>   'Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.'

When I remove the `file` parameter then no error appears. Why does it not recognize my defined constructor and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your code seems ok, you shouldn't be getting this error. Is this what you're trying to compile exactly? Also, how are you building this? What is this error message? What's "severity: 'Fehler'"?

Comment: This error message comes from vscode actually and it's set to German localization. That serverity isn't relevant here. I get the exact same error also when running `tsc` in the root of my nodejs module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a DO'H in it.

```
export class SourceContext {
    constuctor(sourceId: string) {
        this._sourceId = sourceId;
    }
...
}
```

Change **constuctor** to *constructor*

Comment: O M G, <blush>, . o O  (damn js)